# How to select image elements with its srcset attribute value using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

for an example ,

```
<img class="page-hero__image" style="" srcset="https://www.thecloroxcompany.com/wp-content/uploads/160602_fastenclorox_103813-1400x0-c-default.jpg 1600w,
                            https://www.thecloroxcompany.com/wp-content/uploads/160602_fastenclorox_103813-1200x0-c-default.jpg 1200w,
                            https://www.thecloroxcompany.com/wp-content/uploads/160602_fastenclorox_103813-1024x0-c-default.jpg 1024w,
                            https://www.thecloroxcompany.com/wp-content/uploads/160602_fastenclorox_103813-800x0-c-default.jpg 800w,
                            https://www.thecloroxcompany.com/wp-content/uploads/160602_fastenclorox_103813-400x0-c-default.jpg 400w" sizes="(min-width: 1200px) 1200px, 100vw" src="https://www.thecloroxcompany.com/wp-content/uploads/160602_fastenclorox_103813-1000x0-c-default.jpg" alt="">
```

I need to select the above img element by the srcset attribute and its value using the `document.querySelectorAll('img[srcset='value']')`. 
How can I do that?

Comment: Please provide more details and if possible add what you have done so far

Comment: i have the above image element as a string format. so i generated a css selector using the tag name, attributes and its values. i need to select the above image element with document.querySelector( ) using the [srcset="value"] . how can i do that

Comment: this not work with u `document.querySelectorAll('img[srcset='value']')` or what ?

Comment: I put the entire srcset attribute value and it doesn't working

Answer (score 0):

you need to find the image element first and filter by srcset

```
var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img'); 
for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    if(images[i].src == srcset) //check with your srcset
       console.log("found image element"); //image[i] has found element
}
```

or you can use this way too

```
document.querySelectorAll('img[srcset="value"]');
```

Comment: is it possible to find the element using document.querySelectorAll('img[srcset*="https://www.thecloroxcompany.com/wp-content/uploads/160602_fastenclorox_103813-1400x0-c-default.jpg 1600w," ]')

Comment: its only working with single value like this 
document.querySelectorAll(`img[srcset*="https://www.thecloroxcompany.com/wp-content/uploads/160602_fastenclorox_103813-1400x0-c-default.jpg 1600w"]`);

how can i use the entire srcset attribute values to the selector?

Comment: you should put all srcset inside the queryselector and replace the doublequotes in srcset to singlequotes and then try

Comment: i tried it and not working. i tried with two values in the srcset attribute like this : 
document.querySelectorAll('img[[srcset*="https://www.thecloroxcompany.com/wp-content/uploads/160602_fastenclorox_103813-1400x0-c-default.jpg 1600w, https://www.thecloroxcompany.com/wp-content/uploads/160602_fastenclorox_103813-1200x0-c-default.jpg 1200w"]]')

it also doesn't working. But if i try with only single value it works perfectly.

Comment: try using multiple srcset img[srcset=""][srcset=""][srcset=""]...